# PHP Laravel правильный сценарий

Tags: php, алгоритм, laravel

Приветствую, только начал изучение Laravel как возник резонный вопрос исходя из того что бизнес логику держать в контроллерах крайне нежелательно.

Простой сценарий:

человек вводит домен в форму, если regex данные совпали (паттерн есть у меня) (полагаю regex проверку делать нужно в контроллере), если домена не существует (эту проверку необходимо делать не в контроллере насколько я понимаю?) то

- создать запись в базе данных
- редиректнуть пользователя на созданный ID домена

иначе

- редиректнуть пользователя на ID домена

Как организовать это не в контроллере и почему так должно быть реализовано. Крайне надеюсь на развернутый ответ, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Для проверки введенного домена можете создать отдельное правило валидации, валидировать лучше в контроллере. Редиректы тоже стоит делать из контроллера, а для создания записи в бд можете сделать метод в модели и вызвать в контроллере.